# Using the jQuery plugin ColorBox in noConflict() mode

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I am using the jQuery plugin ColorBox in a Joomla! theme, and am having a hard time getting it to work in noConflict() mode. I have the following code that calls my jQuery and the noConflict(); call, followed by my actual jQuery markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="PATH TO COLORBOX"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('a.colorbox').colorbox();
    })
</script>
```

However, I simply cannot get it to work under noConflict() mode. when disabling the no conflict mode it works no worries, but then the associated Mootools scripts in Joomla do not work.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?
Much Appreciated,
Simon

Comment: Are you using any other library on your page other than jquery?

Comment: What Colorbox plugin are you using? A quick search on google seems to throw up several jQuery plugins named Colorbox.

Comment: Well Joomla! uses Mootools library in it's core, hence I am wanting to call jQuery in noconflict mode. I confirm that it works, I can manipulate the DOM, it's just COLOROBX that refuses to work in noConflict() mode. I examined the source, and it seems as though it's wrapped in the appropriate wrapper to use noConflict()

Comment: @Mario Version I am using: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Comment: Many Google results all suggest simply calling jQuery as something like var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); and replacing $ with $j but still not working for this plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that after all of this, it was related to the order in which Joomla! was calling scripts. So for all those who stumble across the same issue, your script calls must all be called AFTER Joomla! include head tag, like follows:

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>templates/helen-o-grady/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){         
        jQuery('a.colorbox').colorbox({iframe:true, width:900, height:650});
        })(jQuery)
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is answer: [How to use no conflict for two types of jquery scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419059/how-to-use-no-conflict-for-two-types-of-jquery-scripts).

I have fixed this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jQuery1_10_2 = $.noConflict(true);
  jQuery1_10_2 (document).ready(function() {
    jQuery1_10_2 (".video-popup").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:850, innerHeight:509, fixed:true});
  });
</script>
```

here .video-popup is my popup wrapper class. change it.