# How to use no conflict for two types of jquery scripts

Tags: colorbox, jquery

I am not a jQuery person, wish I was. I have fiddled with no conflict, but it still lets only one of the scripts work at a time, not both. I am using a scroll to jquery script and colorbox (like lightbox) Here is my code. Any help is awesome.

```
    <!--jquery scroll-->

<script src="js_scroll/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js_scroll/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script src="js_scroll/jquery.nav.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {$('#nav').onePageNav();});

</script>


<!--colorbox-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
            $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
            $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
            $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
            $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
            $(".ajax").colorbox();
            $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
            $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
            });

            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
            $("#click").click(function(){ 
                $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Is this exactly your code ? Why do you link jquery two times (jquery.js and https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js) ?

Comment: And where is your call to `jQuery.noConflict();`?

Comment: I had the no conflict before and then I took it out because it wasn't working. I link jquery both times because the directions to use each script tell me how to implement them. I am not a jquery person and I don't know how to combine them to make them work together.

Comment: Are you changing all your jquery selectors ie. $('.myclass').somefunction to jQuery('.myclass').somefunction ?

Comment: -John, I had heard of this, like I said, where would I do this, in the js files themselves?

Comment: Please help, where would I change the jquery selectors?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load multiple jQuery libraries, this is the way.

```
<script src='jquery-1.3.2.js'></script>
<script>
var $j132 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script src='jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script>
var $j142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

now use $j132() for jQuery 1.3.2 operations and $j142() for jQuery 1.4.2

Comment: That very much depends on what order the scripts were added to the page. Your code will only be correct if jQuery 1.3.2 was added AFTER jQuery 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ColorBox and ScrollBar I solved by using the 
`<script>var $jQuery171 = $.noConflict(true);</script>` after my scroll bar java
the final results was

```
<!--colorbox-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
            $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
            $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
            $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
            $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
            $(".ajax").colorbox();
            $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
            $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
            });

            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
            $("#click").click(function(){ 
                $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and then come the scroll bar java

```
<!--Scroll Plans-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../siteroots/aboutScroll/general.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var $jQuery171 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../siteroots/aboutScroll/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../siteroots/aboutScroll/facescroll.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){ // on page DOM load
        $('#demo1').alternateScroll();  
    })
</script>
<!--End Scroll Plans-->
```

I used the `<script>var $jQuery171 = $.noConflict(true);</script>` in the scroll Java only and it's working fine now.

Comment: see here a very good tutorial about `$.noConflict` hope it helps [link](http://conceptf1.blogspot.com/2013/12/conflict-in-multiple-jquery-files-on-same-page.html)